# Q function vs action-value function

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Is **Q function** synonymous to **action-value function**? I see it used interchangeably and also together ( ex. "Q action-value function" ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Q-function is the term that is used for approximating Q-value which is same as the action-value function. 
In other words, when a function approximation is used to get the Q-value for any arbitrary state-action, that function is called Q-function.